# Axios post only returns empty string (react)?

Tags: asp.net, axios

I tried every different syntax I could find but it's either 405/415 or empty string. Network shows status 200 and DataForm: `{"name":"test"}`:

Thank you for your time!

```
const user = {
    name: 'test'
};

axios(
{
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://localhost:44348/api/user/AddUser`,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(user)
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(user); // {name: "test"}
    console.log(res); // {data: "", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
    console.log(res.data); // empty string
})
```

console:

```
{name: "test"}
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

Controller (asp.net api):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddUser")]
    public void Post1(string obj)
    {
        memory.Add(new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), UserName = obj, Password = "343454" });
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? Your code states that you get a `200` responds code and you get data.

Comment: I get empty string instead of 'test'

Comment: Database on api end also recieves empty string

Comment: You mean in the `data` key of the returning object? I think you're going to have to share more of your backend code

Comment: yes, what do you think would be relevant?

Comment: The bit that sets up the endpoint and returns data. I'm not familiar with ASP.NET which I assume this question is mainly about

Comment: no, my problem is that the backend, the controller does not receive data (or at least it's bad format)

Comment: To me it looks like the `POST` request to `https://localhost:44348/api/user/AddUser` returns an object with an empty `data` key. So I would look into the code that generates that responds. Good luck

Comment: thank you, I thoght the data key signaled what was sent out but then I look into it

Answer (score 0):

> A controller that returns void will produce an EmptyResult.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/may/extreme-asp-net-dissecting-an-asp-net-mvc-controller.

The log looks like it is showing the axios response object which would mean that the server response body is in the data field. You can change your controller to return an ActionResult and return a response as follows which should return the user object.

```
[HttpPost] [Route("AddUser")]
public ActionResult Post1(string obj)
{
   var user = new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), UserName = obj, Password = "343454" };
   memory.Add(user);
   return Ok(user);
}
```